# ADF: Can't see long outputText without spaces in tooltips on rollover in firefox

Tags: jsf, firefox, oracle-adf

I have a fixed area where i want to show some value which could be too long without any spaces. So I have used truncateAt so the text could be seen in ellipsis and on rollover user could see the complete text in the tooltip. In IE I am able to see the complete text in tooltip as after a certain point text moves to the next line. But in Firefox the text is shown in one line and without showing completely it gets cut after a certain point.

I want complete text should be visible in tooltip in multiple lines.

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2">                              
    <af:outputText value="AlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongnglonglongnglonglongGGG AlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongnglonglongnglonglongGGG"
            inlineStyle="white-space: pre-wrap pre-line; width:100px;"  noWrap="true"  truncateAt="10"/>
</af:panelFormLayout>
```

I am using JDeveloper ver.11.1.2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Firefox` bug [from years](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=141).

A possible solution could be installing the [Long Titles](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/long-titles/) extension, which unfortunatelly is not available for the latest `Firefox` versions.

Comment: Is it possible that we could handle this problem with CSS in jsf files